# Grails: plugins: drools vs drools-gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, drools

I am going to try to add some DROOLS into my Grails project.  I have never used DROOLS before, and I intend to learn it within the context of Grails.  Can anyone explain the difference or just say "use that one" for the two plugins: "install plugin drools" vs "install plugin drools-gorm"?

Ostensibly, I would think I want drools-gorm, but is it ever really that simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you probably want grools-gorm. But read this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/grails-activiti-plugin/browse_thread/thread/ee195a55fce216cc?pli=1